# Adding a button anywhere in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

Without using the Swing GUI on Eclipse, I've been struggling with adding a button to a `JFrame` anywhere in the frame (so no `BorderLayout.CENTER`).  I can't get past:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton OKButton = new JButton("OK");
OKButton.addActionListener(new MyAction());
panel.add(OKButton,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

So would something like this be completely redesigned or is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: By Anywhere (as I'm planning to add more than one button/label to a frame), I meant perhaps a coordinate on the frame. So other than dead center, (example) 75% from the left and 25% down.

Comment: What do you mean by "anywhere"? Please give us the gory details.

Comment: Your best bet is to read up on and use the layout managers as they will make your GUI creation ***much*** easier. You can find the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Comment: *"adding a button to a jFrame anywhere in the frame"*  Don't do that.  Instead add it 'somewhere' that is 'logical' (i.e. according to layout manager).  If you are making a drag-n-drop GUI designer, just ..don't.

Comment: *"75% from the left and 25% down"*   `GridBagLayout` accepts weights.  I think so does `MigLayout` & possibly other 3rd party layouts.

Answer (score 4):

You can use different Panels with different LayoutMangers to arrange the GUI as you like.

Have a look here for some common LayoutManagers:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Otherwise you could use the null Layout (panel.setLayout(null)) and place all components by setting the position. But I would recommend you the LayoutMangers